# Accessing remote clipboard buffers

Tags: c++, macos, x11, copy-paste, xcb

Is anyone familiar with the correct method to access clipboard buffers on client machines by remote machines that are forwarding X Windows to the client machines?

I am in the situation where I have developed code using XCB that is running remotely on a server running linux and forwarding windows to Mac OSX running XQuartz, and I need to create copy and paste features in the program such that when text is pasted into the window on the Mac OSX side, the clipboard contents are sent to the remote server.

If it matters, the X forwarding connection is set up with SSH "-X" option.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you may check virtualbox guest additions implementation of clipboard sharing for Linux guests.

Comment: Description unclear. Do you have two different X servers running on two computers?

Comment: The remote server is an X server (linux based) and the mac is a client, I think? Using XQuartz. I'm not using virtual box, this is an actual, physical remote server, unless you mean to look at the source code and extrapolate (?)